# javascritp no puede leer la propiedad length

Tags: javascript, html5

hola estoy haciendo un bucle for para recorrer un arreglo llamado tasks , pero me dice que no se puede leer la propiedad length, que podrá ser?

```
document.getElementById("formTask").addEventListener("submit",saveTask);

function saveTask(e) {

    let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    let description = document.getElementById("description").value;

    const task ={
        title,
        description
    };

    if (localStorage.getItem("tasks")===null){

        let tasks = [];
        tasks.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem("task",JSON.stringify(tasks));
} else {

    let tasks = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    tasks.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem("tasks",JSON.stringify(tasks));

}
    e.preventDefault();

}

function getTasks(){

    let tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    let tasksView =  document.getElementById("tasks");

    tasksView.innerHTML = ``;

    for(let i = 0; i <= tasks.length ;i++){
        console.log(tasks[i]);
    }
}
getTasks();
```

Comment: Hola @samuel_rojas acabo de revisar la documentación de window.localStorage indican que algunos browsers la soportan permitiendo que sea deshabilitada y otros como safari le dan cuota 0 haciendo que sea no usable. Debes verificar que esté disponible y habilitada. Mira este enlace: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: he revisado la documentación me fue muy util muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede es que no puedes obtener el length de un json

Pero puedes hacerlo asi:

```
for(let x in tasks ){
   console.log(x);
}
```

O tambien con

```
let count = Object.keys(tasks).length;
```

Comment: gracias logre hacerlo con el bucle for que ejemplificaste. te lo agradezco